# if swing components fade-away trick using is not suggested?

Tags: java, swing, animation, awt

I'm actually still digging up into the Java SE (desktop app),
and now i'm a bit curious while actually trying to do some animation
fading in and out of the swing components.

I found out this article. [Oracle Web Link](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/#Setting-the-Opacity-Level-of-a-Window).

But there is a note over there saying that the imported **com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities** 
is not suggested to be used while we're doing some implementation (updates may change the imported library).

THen, what's the alternative of this fading out tricks?
I found out trident library has no new updates lately...

hope there's some shade of light upon this matter. :D

Comment: *"hope there's some shade of light.."*  No, but there is an opacity.  ;)

Comment: Hey gumuruh: please accept some answers to your questions!

Comment: Kirill's code (Author of Trident has stopped further dev on it) The forks of his work can be picked up here: http://shemnon.com/speling/

Comment: ya ya, camickr... i did already.
thanks for reminding me Hovercrat Full of Eels. 

i jumped too many forums and forgotten the rest. 
but now the previous questions accepted already.

is there's something left ? (hehe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning that [`com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities` is not part of an officially supported API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/#Setting-the-Opacity-Level-of-a-Window) may derive from plans to incorporate a similar API in [Java 7: Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/).

Comment: to incorporate? do you mean that warning will still exist even until java 7 released? :o

Comment: I'm not sure when the API will be frozen; all we are told is that it hasn't been deferred to Java 8, as of 2011/5/16.